# SQL Server : Triggers for Insert

Tags: sql-server, triggers

```
create table tab(id int identity,task_id int,task_descp varchar(10),task_code varchar(10))

insert into tab values(7,'BUS','B')
insert into tab values(3,'CAR','C')

create table tab_detail(  task_descp varchar(10),task_code varchar(10),color varchar(10))

create trigger tab_trigger on tab for insert as
  declare @task_descp varchar(10)
  declare @task_code varchar(10)
  declare @task_id int
  set @task_descp=i.task_descp from inserted i
  set @task_code=i.task_code from inserted i 
  set @task_id=i.task_id from inserted i
  if(@task_id=7)
    insert into tab_detail values(@task_descp,@task_code,'BLUE')
  if(@task_id=3)
    insert into tab_detail values(@task_descp,@task_code,'GREEN')
go
```

I want to create a trigger for table `tab` where if I insert a record based on the `task_id` column a record has to be inserted into another table `tab_detail`.

When executing this I get this error:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'from'

Comment: Your **fundamental flaw** is that you seem to expect the trigger to be fired **once per row** and thus `Inserted` will only contain a single row. This is **NOT** the case! The trigger will fire **once per statement**; and `Inserted` can contain lots of rows. In that case, your `set @task_id=i.task_id from inserted i` is going to pick one arbitrary row from `Inserted` (undetermined which one that'll be) and will ignore all the rest....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of:

```
set @task_descp=i.task_descp from inserted i
```

Try this:

```
select @task_descp=i.task_descp from inserted i
```

Or you could do this:

```
create trigger tab_trigger on tab for insert as

       insert into tab_detail
       select task_descp, task_code, case @task_id when 7 then 'BLUE' else 'GREEN' end
       from inserted 
       where taskid in (7,3)

go
```

Comment: What if there are multiple records?  The select fixes the compile issue but not the possible run time one.

Comment: I will change my answer to answer your comment

Answer (score 1):

Change the SET to SELECT.  Also, inserted is a recordset, not a single value.  Fixing the code issue still might result in a run time issue!

This code should work fine for a recordset of information.

```
CREATE TRIGGER tab_trigger ON tab FOR INSERT AS
BEGIN

-- nothing to do?
IF (@@rowcount = 0) RETURN;

-- do not count rows
SET NOCOUNT ON;

-- inserted data
INSERT INTO tab_detail 
  SELECT 
      i.task_descp,
      i.task_code,
      CASE i.taskcode
          WHEN 7 THEN 'BLUE'
          WHEN 3 THEN 'GREEN'
          ELSE ''
      END
  FROM inserted i
  WHERE i.task_code in (3, 7)

END
GO
```